# ArrayList Searching Multiple Words

Tags: java

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(myList, SearchWord);
System.out.println(myList.get(index));
```

Actually, i stored 1 million words to Array List, now i need to search the particular word through the key. The result is not a single word, it may contain multiple words.

Example is suppose if i type "A" means output is [Aarhus, Aaron, Ababa,...]. The result depends on searching word. How can i do it and which sorting algorithm is best in Collections.

Comment: For your requirement you have to choose trie datastructure. That will give you what u need (Suggester) in a easy way.

Comment: Your kind of search best matches fuzzy search. I suggest you choose a search engine for it. like Appache lucene it'll be very fast,reliable and easy to manage. Moreover keeping arraylist of one million words is not a good idea.

Comment: Regarding your example, do you always need words that start with a particular string?

Comment: no. suppose if i type unmatch word means no need of result.

Comment: @Sathesh You should choose Trie data structure. If you find the node with the given text and do a traversal from there, you will get what you want.   http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/trie-insert-and-search/ Take a look on this. If you do it in an array your complexity will increase.

Answer (score 0):

Options:

1. If you want to stick to the array list, sort it before you search. Then find first key that matches your search criteria and iterate from it onward until you find a key that does not match. Collect all matching keys into some buffer structure. Bingo, you have your answer.
2. Change data structure to a tree. Either

   1. a simple binary tree - your get all keys sorted automatically. Navigate the tree in depth first fashion. Until you find a key that does not match.
   2. a fancy trie structure. That way you get your get all keys sorted automatically plus you get a significant performance boost due to efficient storage. Rest is the same, navigate the tree, collect matching keys.